# Running Geoprocessing tools via ArcGIS Pro SDK

Tags: vb.net, arcgis-pro-sdk

I'm new to the ArcGIS Pro SDK and I find it very difficult to migrate my ArcGIS Add-In to ArcGIS Pro.

I simply want to take the union of two shapefiles. When I run the code, nothing happens. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I am using version ArcGIS Pro 2.9.

```
Dim shapefilepath1 As String = "D:\data\area1.shp"
Dim shapefilepath2 As String = "D:\data\area2.shp"
Dim output As String = "D:\try\GPoutput.shp"
Dim myarray As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

myarray.Add(shapefilepath1)
myarray.Add(shapefilepath2)
myarray.Add(output)

Dim parameters As IReadOnlyList(Of String) = Geoprocessing.MakeValueArray(myarray.ToArray)
Dim gpresult1 = Geoprocessing.ExecuteToolAsync("C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolBox\toolboxes\Analysis Tools.tbx\Union", myarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the filename of the tool in the toolbox, you can use its tool name ("analysis.Union"), which is found in the tool [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/union.htm) under the Python tab.

This is how I have one of my GP tools set up (and while it in C#, it should be easy to translate to VB.Net). I call the function with the arguments and returning the Task Result. I can then test whether it was successful or not.

```
public static async Task<IGPResult> DissolveFeatures(FeatureClass featureClass, string DissolveFields, string StatsFields, string OutputName, GPExecuteToolFlags flags = GPExecuteToolFlags.None)
{
  List<object> arguments = new()
  {
    featureClass,
    OutputName,
    DissolveFields,
    StatsFields
  };
  IGPResult result = await Geoprocessing.ExecuteToolAsync("management.Dissolve", Geoprocessing.MakeValueArray(arguments.ToArray()), null, null, null, flags);
  return result;
}

IGPResult dissolveResult = await Utilities.DissolveFeatures(virtualFC, StrataFieldName, StatField, $"{path}\\Dissolve", GPExecuteToolFlags.AddToHistory);
if (dissolveResult.IsFailed)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dissolveResult.Messages.ToArray().ToString());
  MessageBox.Show("Dissolve failed");
  return false;
}
```